# get row number along results from a sqlite query

Tags: sqlite

I am doing

```
sqlite file.db "select ... " | nl
```

To number every row in the resultset. How do I get rid `nl` ? in other words, how do I do it in sql ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about

```
SELECT ROWID,* FROM ...;
```

Or try `ROW_NUMBER()` if you're on SQLite v. 3.25.0 or higher
See [How to use ROW_NUMBER in sqlite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16847574/how-to-use-row-number-in-sqlite)

Comment: `ROWID` doesn't enumerate the rows, it gives you the row ID, which is an internal ID used by sqlite, but `ROW_NUMBER()` is a function that generates sequential numbers for every result set.

Answer (score 2):

If you're on SQLite v. 3.25.0 or higher:

```sql
select
  row_number() over (order by '') as "#"
, *
from data
;
```

Comment: This was helpful, but I changed the [`over` clause](https://www.sqlite.org/windowfunctions.html). What does `order by ''` actually do? Aren't there better alternatives?

Comment: @Wolf as far as I understand, `row_number()` is a window function, so there must be a window. `(order by '')` creates inline window. You can change it to `row_number() over () as "#"`.

Comment: Thanks for stopping by, now I have another something to experiment with. ;)